# Excel file with 1GB size

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a Excel file that contains 600 small images, I've tried to use Excel image compression but it did nothing, is there another easy way to really compress these images?

Comment: what exactly you've tried? Have you set resolution to the smallest one? Applied to all pictures?

Comment: I selected all images, clicked "Compress Images" in Format tab, compressed all, no change at all. I've set the smallest resolution 96dpi, the images are small, like 200px width 80 height. I guess excel resizes the image keeping the original size image, so it's size continues big.

Comment: My question here would be why are you using 600+ images in excel?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question came up for Word pictures and using copy and paste special as jpeg seems to reduce file size considerably (see [How to automate 'paste as JPEG' for pasting pics in Word so as to reduce the entire document size?](https://superuser.com/questions/1013190/how-to-automate-paste-as-jpeg-for-pasting-pics-in-word-so-as-to-reduce-the-ent))

Try a macro to loop through pictures and copy and paste special as jpeg:

```
Sub test()

Dim shp As Object
If ActiveSheet.Pictures.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

For i = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Count To 1 Step -1

   Set shp = ActiveSheet.Pictures(i)

        shp.Select

        Dim iTop As Integer
        Dim iLeft As Integer
        iTop = Selection.Top
        iLeft = Selection.Left


        Selection.Cut

        ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (JPEG)", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False

        Selection.Left = iLeft
        Selection.Top = iTop

Next

End Sub
```